# Почему не срабатывает отрицательный ответ?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void Авторизация_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
        var result=new System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult();
      result = MessageBox.Show("Вы уверены?", "Внимание",
                      MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                      MessageBoxIcon.Question);
      if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
      {
          Application.Exit();
      }
      else 
      {
          return;
      }
    }
```

Все равно закрывается форма, даже при отрицательном результате.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FormsClosed`- это слишком поздно.

```
private void Авторизация_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    var result = new System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult();
    result = MessageBox.Show("Вы уверены?", "Внимание",
                  MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                  MessageBoxIcon.Question);
    if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
    else 
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: А е, спасибо :D. Все никак не мог понять в чем трабл. Через 6 минут отмечу как ответ.